# How to embedd mp3 download on website

Tags: javascript, html, web, download, mp3

Let's say I have a medium sized mp3 library (a few gigs), with various folders and subfolders, that I'd like to have available on my website for users to download. How would I go about doing this? Please don't assume any prior knowledge about DB's and the like, thank you! (don't mind which language, just one that is most efficient/easy is proffered...)

Comment: Are you concerned about appearence? If not, why don't you just serve the top folder and let the users browse and download the files?

Comment: You can use PHP for the backend, reading the files/folders and outputting links to them in HTML. No need for a database, really, although it would make searching easier. I would recommend some sort of ready-made script, if you know nothing about programming. I would also recommend `mod_xsendfile` on the server to serve the download-requests.

Comment: There is an HTML attribute `audio` you can use that for adding audio.
Check this link [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

Comment: @karliwson please elaborate on what it means to "serve the top folder"? It sounds promising...

Comment: Any web server can serve folders and files. The user can navigate through the folder structure and download the files. If you tell which web server you're using (web hosting or a server of your own? Apache? Nginx?) I can give you an idea on how to do it.